# Force push current branch

Tags: git, git-push, git-alias

I often rebase feature branches and then want to force push them to the server.

```
git push --force origin feature-mongodb-support
```

Is there any shortcut for `git push --force origin <current branch>`?

Comment: I always set up the config/tracking such that `git push` alone pushes to the default remote tracking branch. If you can do that, you could get down to `git push -f`? (just curious: what's your backup plan in this workflow if you push a bad rebase? I assume you're the only one working on these feature branches?)

Comment: Isn't this question specifically about how to get rid of the current branch name in the often used `git push -f origin <current branch name>` construct? Then the accepted answer completely misses the point and @Mike's comment should be the accepted answer.

Comment: I think the best answer is to set it as default: `git config --global push.default current` (from [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/948397/450913)).

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You can use aliases to shorten the command. Use it like this:

```
git config --global alias.fpush "push --force origin"
```

Now to push your branch just type:

```
git fpush feature-mongodb-support
```

Or you can even hardcode the branch name into the command:

```
git alias fpush "push --force origin feature-mongodb-support"
```

and use only `git fpush` to push your precious work into the upstream.

However, non-fast-forward updates are dangerous since you will basically overwrite all the history on server that occurred between the last merge/rebase into your local branch and the forced push. If you need to do them often there is definitely **something wrong** in your workflow.

Comment: I am the only one working on a feature branch. I just want to keep the feature branche fast-forwardable against the master branch to make my life easier. Is there anything wrong with that?

Comment: Yep, it is risky. You will overwrite your branch with just one command. A better point will be to interactively rebase your feature-branch on top of the master branch once the feature is done. You will still have a clean history in your master and there will be no risk regarding all these overwrites.

Comment: I do this, because I need to incorporate new changes from the master branch to test if the new feature still works with the new master code. Where's the risk?

Comment: The risk is on overwriting remote branch (together with its history) with some buggy code and loosing your previous work. If this is of no concern to you - just use the solution from the answer.

Comment: Oh, sure. But if I just do a `git rebase master` in the feature branch, then nothing bad can happen. Am I right?

Comment: It can. Depends on the actual changes in master. So it is up to you to decide whether the risk is acceptable :)

Comment: The `git rebase master` at least allows you to back out if the rebase doesn't happen cleanly (via `git rebase --abort`)

Comment: If you follow this advice and include the remote name (typically `origin`) in your git alias, you may have problems with bash `[tab]` completion still trying to add the remote instead of skipping straight to offering branch names. To fix this, define your own custom replacement function in `~/.profile` after sourcing bash_completion: `_git_fpush() { _git_branch; }` (where "fpush" matches the name of your git alias.) This will cause bash to treat your alias the same as the `branch` command.

Comment: You say frequent force pushes are wrong. There are 2 ways to update long-living branches: merge and rebase. When you choose the rebase method, you need to force push. How else would you do that, if the requirement is to have a clean, straight history on the branch?

Comment: @BenBucksch imagine you have 10 developers working on this branch and between your rebase and forced push someone else has pushed his payload to that branch. The result will be you just overwrite their work with your forced push. Keeping history streamlined this way is ok for long-lasting private branches, and here by private I mean situations when there's only a few developers on that branch. For branches where tens of developers are collaborating, forced pushes will wreck havoc.

Comment: Agreed, force push works only when there's a single developer. (Or manual coordination, which is to be avoided.)

Answer (score 9):

After reading these answers and reading this answer to a related question (https://stackoverflow.com/a/18782415/586), I created this alias to force push to `origin` based on the current branch name:

```
fp = "!git push -f origin \"$(git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD)\""
```

Comment: How would this work if the remote branch (that we push to) does not have the same name as the local branch?

Comment: @user1021726 it doesn't.

Comment: This is the answer that cover the whole question... with the limitation that the local branch and remote branch need to have the same name.

Comment: @jlleblanc is there any way for me to exclude master? i.e. "force push current branch to origin ONLY IF the current branch is something other than master" -- reason for this is because sometimes I accidentally do "git fp" on master and if there are no branch protection rules in place on the repo, that would be bad

Answer (score 9):

You can change the default behaviour by setting the **push.default** property :

```
git config --global push.default current
```

then:

```
git push -f
```

will force a push to you current branch.

Here is a copy/paste from http://schacon.github.io/git/git-config.html:

> ***push.default***
>
> Defines the action git push should take if no refspec is given on the command line, no refspec is configured in the remote, and no refspec is implied by any of the options given on the command line. 
>   Possible values are:
>
> - **nothing** - do not push anything.
> - **matching** - push all matching branches. All branches having the same name in both ends are considered to be matching. This is the default.
> - **upstream** - push the current branch to its upstream branch.
> - **tracking** - deprecated synonym for upstream.
> - **current** - push the current branch to a branch of the same name.

Comment: Works beautifully, and does exactly what the OP asked. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

If you use [oh my zsh](https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/) you can simply do

```
ggfl
```

which will do this for you

```
git push --force-with-lease origin <your_argument>/$(current_branch)
```

https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/wiki/Cheatsheet

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick:

```
git alias fpush "push --force origin"
```

Which will let you use `git fpush` as a shorter alternative.

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken, this pushes *all* branches which happen to have local changes, including potentially master, or completely unrelated branches, not just the current branch. Combined with the force push, this is extremely dangerous.

Answer (score 0):

To automatically force-push to the *branch that is tracked* (regardless of its name and upstream), I've devised this alias:

```
fbrpush=!git push $(git rev-parse --abbrev-ref=loose --symbolic-full-name @{upstream} \
                    | sed 's:/: +:')
```

**(line is broken for readability)**

*(based on [another SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9753364/9288580))*

Answer (score 0):

The current branch name can also be inferred automatically.

I use a small shell script to do the force push to the current branch:

```
git branch | grep '*' | awk '{print $2}' | xargs -I % git push origin % -f
```

The command `git branch` tags the current branch with `*` symbol, so we can get the relevant line with `grep '*'` and parse it to get the branch name.

Then the shortcut command can be defined as an alias in `.bashrc` or `.zshrc`:

```
alias gfp=/path/to/script
```

**Update.**

Since Git 2.22 (see this answer: stackoverflow.com/a/6245587/1326411 ) it can be simplified to:

```
alias git-fp='git branch --show-current | xargs -I % git push origin % --force-with-lease'
```

Comment: there are easier ways: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6245587/1326411

Comment: Thank you so much! That looks much more elegant :)

Answer (score 0):

to expand on @jlleblanc 's good answer, if you want to add a protection to prevent force pushing to master (this can be really hard to undo)

```
[alias]
    fp = "!branch=$(git branch --show-current); [[ -z $branch || $branch = 'master' ]] && echo 'Command cannot be used on master branch or when not on branch.' || git push -f origin \"$(git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD)\""
```

it will do the same thing, except if current branch is master it will skip and print warning