# Git command to add, commit, and push to the correct branch

Tags: git

In this question [Git command to commit all changes including files removed or created](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20287206/git-command-to-commit-all-changes-including-files-removed-or-created) the answer given allows me to add, commit and push all changes made to my `master` branch in one command with:

```
git commitall "a message describing what you did"
```

where `commitall` is the user defined command:

```
commitall = "!func(){ git add -A && git commit -am \"$1\" && git push origin master; }; func"
```

stored in the file `~\.gitconfig` under the section `[alias]`.

The problem is that this command only works when I'm positioned in the `master` branch. How could I generalize this command so it will check in which branch I'm currently positioned and push the changes to *that branch*?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have done (see "[git - `push current` vs. `push upstream` (tracking)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13751847/6309)"):

```
git config push.default simple
# or at least
git config push.default current
```

Then your `git push origin` (no branch specified) will always push only the *current* branch.

If not, replace the `git push origin master` in your alias with:

```
git push -u origin \"$(git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD)\"
```

More at "[Git alias on current branch](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15112280/6309)".

Comment: I have not done `git config push.default simple`, I don't even know what that is. Could you expand a bit please?

Comment: `git config push.default current`?

Comment: I was also wondering what the difference between simple and current was.

Comment: @AlexanderYancharuk was that a question to me or VonC? If it was directed at me, I have not done `git config push.default current` and I also don't know what it means. Sorry, brand new to `git` here. _Edit_: oh I see you were asking VonC.

Comment: @VonC Thanks, Im still on 1.7.10 so even didn't knew about `simple` parameter.

Comment: @AlexanderYancharuk yes, `current` can work too. I have edited my answer.

Comment: @VonC so if I do a `git config push.default current` (I'm using `v1.7.9.5` so no `simple` command) it will tell `git` to always push to the current branch I'm in when I run `git push origin`, thus I don't need to specify the branch anymore. Did I understand that correctly?

Comment: @AlexanderYancharuk 1.7.10? April 2012? That seems so old ;) There are much more recent packages out there: http://superuser.com/q/644586/141

Comment: @VonC Thanks! Got 1.8.4 from backports. It has `simple` param. +1 from me when I run out of votelimit :)