# Can I push and pull without explicit branch specifying?

Tags: git

I do not want to type `git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/<branch> myBranchName`.

I tried

```
[push]
    default = current
```

but it works only for push, not for pull, `[pull]` do nothing.

Also tried

```
[branch]
    autosetupmerge = always
    autosetuprebase = always
```

My git version is 2.35 (current stable in Gentoo) so `push.autoSetupRemote` is unavailable for me. Only custom aliases, no simple config option?

Comment: You can set up a git alias

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Git alias on current branch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15112280/git-alias-on-current-branch)

Comment: Why don't you want to type `git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/<branch> myBranchName`? Would it not solve your problem?

Comment: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-pull#_default_behaviour

Comment: Upstreams are overrated. I never use them. I never say `pull` either. I have a feeling this is an xy question and you should really be questioning your working habits.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`branch.autosetupmerge=always` is almost certainly **not** what you want; it will cause all new branches you create to use their source as the upstream - even if you branch from another local branch.

As of git 2.37+, you probably want to set these two things:

`git config --global branch.autoSetupMerge simple`: This will set up the upstream automatically, but only if the new local branch name matches the remote branch name.

`git config --global push.autoSetupRemote true`: This will automatically set up tracking when you push new branches - it also makes `git push` "just work" for new branches.

Answer (score 0):

I'm on an ancient 2.24 and use `push.default=current` in my config.

```
[push]
        default = current
```

Also, even without this you don't need to type the `set-upstream` command. `git push` should type it for you and then you can just copy/paste it.

For example:

```
❯ git push
fatal: The current branch feature/test has no upstream branch.
To push the current branch and set the remote as upstream, use

    git push --set-upstream origin feature/test

(select and right click here)
❯  git push --set-upstream origin feature/tm/test
```

Comment: But this config is only for push, not pull.

Comment: Once you push this branch you're repo will have the link stored in `.git/config`

Comment: But I want to pull and push without `--set-upstream` for every new branch - is that possible?

Comment: Yes, that's what `push.default=current` does. The rest of my answer is just to say that even if you don't have the setting you don't need to type you just copy/paste. But if you have the setting you don't need copy/paste.

Comment: I have `[push] default = current` in my global git config but still cannot `git pull` on new branch without additional something :(

Comment: I don't understand now. When you say you cannot `git pull`, what do you mean? Normally you can `git pull` and then `git checkout branch_name`

Comment: I can `git pull -u origin branchname`, but I want `git pull`

Comment: `git pull` doesn't have `-u` option :/

Comment: Ops I mean `git pull origin branchname`