# Branch autocompletion does not work with git alias for push

Tags: git, bash, autocomplete, bash-completion

I am using Git with [git-completion](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/contrib/completion/git-completion.bash) and everything works fine with a single exception: when I do

`git p some_remote [TAB]`

I get as autocomplete suggestions the files in the current directory (wrong). `p` is a Git alias:

```
$ cat ~/.gitconfig
[alias]
    p = push
```

Still, when I do:

```
git push some_remote [TAB]
```

I get as suggestions the branches in the current repository (correct). In both cases the completion for `some_remote` works correctly.

What is the reason for this?

Comment: This is now fixed (April 2014, Git 2.0): see [my revised answer below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20218023/6309).

Comment: As a variant on this, if your alias looks like this: `git config --global alias.p "push origin"` (so it also includes a default remote), tab completion breaks and still tries to offer remotes instead of skipping to branches. To fix this, define your own replacement function in `~/.profile` after sourcing git-completion.bash: `_git_p() { _git_branch; }` (where "p" matches the name of your git alias.) This will cause bash to treat your alias the same as the `branch` command. After this, `git p[tab]` will suggest branches, instead of remotes. See also: https://stackoverflow.com/q/11453807/70876

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's a bug!

`git-completion.bash` *does* [go through your git aliases](https://github.com/git/git/blob/v1.8.5/contrib/completion/git-completion.bash#L2531-L2535), wiring each up to the right completion function.

But then four of those—the functions for `git push`, `fetch`, `pull`, and `remote`—delegate to `__git_complete_remote_or_refspec()`, which [starts like this](https://github.com/git/git/blob/v1.8.5/contrib/completion/git-completion.bash#L521):

```sh
__git_complete_remote_or_refspec ()
{
    local cur_="$cur" cmd="${words[1]}"
    ...
```

`$words` is just the list of tokens from the command line, and a few lines down, it starts checking `$cmd` without expanding aliases, [for example](https://github.com/git/git/blob/v1.8.5/contrib/completion/git-completion.bash#L567-L589):

```sh
case "$cmd" in
fetch)
  # ...
pull|remote)
  # ...
```

As far as I can tell, **Gábor Szeder** [first reported this two years ago](http://markmail.org/message/dbzfr2noidiioifw) in a thread about making completion work with shell aliases.

He mentioned it again in 2012 [in reply to a patch](http://markmail.org/message/jh6kjqnnjttdx4od) from **Felipe Contreras** (@felipec). Last month, Felipe [announced](http://felipec.wordpress.com/2013/10/28/git-fc/) his [fork of git](https://github.com/felipec/git), which actually has a self-contained patch for this: [`b7b6be72`](https://github.com/felipec/git/commit/b7b6be72d60d5d5fc308a0bb7d48508ff70f3998).

I don't know if that's been submitted upstream, but in the meantime... if you want to test it out, apply the patch to your `git-completion.bash`:

```sh
curl https://github.com/felipec/git/commit/b7b6be72d60d.diff |
  patch -d [directory containing git-completion.bash]
  # useful options for patch: --verbose --dry-run
```

If you don't know where your current `git-completion.bash` lives, try `declare -F`:

```sh
dirname "$(shopt -s extdebug; declare -F __git_complete | awk '{ print $3 }')"
```

(After patching `git-completion.bash`, it'll prompt you for the location of `git-completion.zsh` to apply the second hunk... you can just hit `^C` to skip it.)

Comment: Interesting, and more precise than my answer. +1

Comment: As you need to source `git-completion.sh`, it's probably easier to just `cat .bashrc` or similar :) Anyway, this works, thanks; hope that they will push it upstream.

Answer (score 3):

Update April 2014, for Git 2.0:

The [commit 880111c](https://github.com/git/git/commit/880111c11befaaf070e8ea1021bf11b4fb58c461) (Felipe Contreras [(`felipec`)](https://github.com/felipec)) now includes:

#### completion: fix completing args of aliased "push", "fetch", etc.

> Some commands need the first word to determine the actual action that is being executed, however, the command is wrong when we use an alias, for example '`alias.p=push`', if we try to complete '`git p origin <TAB>`', the result would be wrong because [`__git_complete_remote_or_refspec()`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/880111c11befaaf070e8ea1021bf11b4fb58c461/contrib/completion/git-completion.bash#L532) doesn't know where it came from.
>
> So let's override `words[1]`, so the alias '`p`' is override by the actual command, '`push`'.

---

`git-completion` doesn't seem to work well with `git alias` or regular alias.

For instance, if you had defined an alias '`gp`' for '`git push`', as in "[How do I get bash completion to work with aliases?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15009611/6309)", you could type:

```
__git_complete gp _git_push
```

Maybe something similar exist for git aliases, as in [this script](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2078422/6309).

Comment: `__git_complete gp _git_push` does not seem to work well for me; it suggests the name of the remote correctly, but then it goes on suggesting the same remote names instead of branches. I already have implemented a variant of your second suggestion, and while it works, it's not perfect because: 1. it's not consistent with my existing git aliases and 2. it's buggy, i.e., it starts suggesting remote/ branch names only after inputting the first letter (I use vim-like completion in bash).

Comment: @adrianp that would be for a regular alias, not a git alias though

Comment: Yes, I understood that :)

Comment: @adrianp ok. Some more tests are in order, then.

Comment: I can confirm on Git 2.4.0 that this is still an issue (confirmed that my `git-complete.bash` has the code added by `880111c`). Are there any relevant GH issues where discussion about this issue is happening? I can't seem to find any other than this with at the least a workaround.