# I can not make a git pull

Tags: git, bitbucket

When I type the command :

$ git pull origin header

This error returned to me :

fatal: Couldn't find remote ref header

When i do git push nothing is taken into account by bitbucket. Where could the problem come from?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11552437/git-pull-remote-branch-cannot-find-remote-ref

Comment: Possible duplicate of [git pull remote branch cannot find remote ref](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11552437/git-pull-remote-branch-cannot-find-remote-ref)

Comment: I am no branch on my repository

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It worked, I had to make a :

$ git config --global push.default current

[Couldn't find remote ref HEAD in Git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20185082/couldnt-find-remote-ref-head-in-git)

[Default behavior of "git push" without a branch specified](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/948354/default-behavior-of-git-push-without-a-branch-specified)