# When doing a 'git push', what does '--set-upstream' do?

Tags: git, push, git-push, git-remote, upstream-branch

What does git `--set-upstream` do?

I tried to understand it by reading the [git manual](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-push), but I didn't quite get it.

Comment: The question does not state the full git command. It can only be inferred that it's about the command `git push --set-upstream`.

Answer (score 680, accepted):

> To avoid confusion,
> recent versions of `git` deprecate this somewhat ambiguous `--set-upstream` option
> in favor of a more verbose `--set-upstream-to` option
> with identical syntax and behavior.
> [ [Reference](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-branch#Documentation/git-branch.txt---set-upstream) ]

---

```
git branch --set-upstream-to <remote-branch>
```

sets the default remote branch for the current local branch.

Any future `git pull` command (with the current local branch checked-out),
will attempt to bring in commits from the `<remote-branch>` into the current local branch.

---

One way to avoid having to explicitly type `--set-upstream` / `--set-upstream-to` is  to use its shorthand flag `-u` as follows:

```
git push -u origin local-branch
```

This sets the upstream association for any future push/pull attempts automatically.
For more details, check out this [**detailed explanation about upstream branches and tracking**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10002469/319204).

Comment: in this command `git push -u origin local-branch` what does the `origin` represent?  Is there any case where I would type anything other than `origin` after the `-u` ?

Comment: @JohnHenckel `origin` refers to the remote git repository that was used to clone from. There can be [**multiple remote git repositories**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11690709/can-a-project-have-multiple-origins). In such a case, `origin` may be replaced with the proper name of the desired remote that one wishes to refer to.

Comment: do a `git remote -v` to find your remotes, the default one is `origin` usually

Answer (score 76):

When you push to a remote and you use the `--set-upstream` flag git sets the branch you are pushing to as the remote tracking branch of the branch you are pushing.

Adding a remote tracking branch means that git then knows what you want to do when you `git fetch`, `git pull` or `git push` in future. It assumes that you want to keep the local branch and the remote branch it is tracking in sync and does the appropriate thing to achieve this.

You could achieve the same thing with `git branch --set-upstream-to` or `git checkout --track`. See the git help pages on [tracking branches](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Branching-Remote-Branches#Tracking-Branches) for more information.

Comment: When I checkout with -t it does set the upstream for pushing, only for pulling.

Comment: This answer is assuming there is a branch being pushed to :D

Answer (score 30):

`git branch --set-upstream <<origin/branch>>` is officially not supported anymore and is replaced by `git branch --set-upstream-to <<origin/branch>>`

Answer (score 9):

`--set-upstream` is used to map a branch in your local to a branch on remote so that you can just do git push or git pull and it will know which branch to push/pull from

**For adding a remote repo I use these commands**

- First, check your remote repositories with `git remote -v`
- If you can't see upstream then use `git remote add upstream <URL>`
- Check again your remote repositories with `git remote -v`

By using the same commands above, it is possible to have multiple remotes to a local repository.

Just change the upstream name `git remote add NAME <URL>`

Answer (score 4):

I'm assuming that your **question** is:

> What does `git push --set-upstream <repository> <branchname>` do?

As you see, I assumed that the git command in question is `git push`. I hope that is what you meant. For simplifying the answer, I further specified that the local branch <branchname> that you are on has the same name as the remote branch on your upstream repository <repository> that you are pushing to. Finally, I assume a common git configuration.

With that said, this is my **answer**:

In addition to the operation that a `git push` without the option `--set-upstream` does, [this option](https://github.com/git/git/blob/v2.32.0/builtin/push.c#L573) makes `git push` [set](https://github.com/git/git/blob/v2.32.0/branch.c#L58) at least two [configuration variables](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#Documentation/git-config.txt-branchltnamegtremote):

- branch.<branchname>.remote = <repository>
- branch.<branchname>.merge  = /ref/heads/<branchname>

That's all this command does. It stores upstream information (i.e., remote repository and branch) for the local branch in config variables.

Upstream information is stored under the local branch name. If your local branch is called `main`, the respective config variables are `branch.main.remote` and `branch.main.merge`. Based on the way how this upstream information is stored, a local branch can have no more than a single set of upstream information.

You can query whether any of these config variables are set using `git config --get-regexp ^branch\.`. This will output any variables that start with "branch."

The magic happens when these config variables are used by, e.g., `git fetch`, `git pull` or `git push` to figure out the upstream repository and remote branch for a local branch if you don't explicitly specify them on the commandline. That is, when these config variables are set, you can just issue `git push` and git will know (using these variables) the remote repository and upstream branch to use.

Suggested further reading:

- [Why do I have to “git push --set-upstream origin ”?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37770467/why-do-i-have-to-git-push-set-upstream-origin-branch)

**But watch out for git quirks**:

If <repository> is given as an URL or file path, see for example [this example](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/working_with_projects.html#push-to-create-a-new-project):

```
git push --set-upstream git@gitlab.example.com:namespace/myproject.git master
```

`git push` does not create a reference to the remote branch head in `.git/refs/remotes/<repository>`

Only if the upstream repository has been given a name using

```
git remote add <repository> <URL>
```

and `git push --set-upstream` has been used with this name, the full power of remote tracking branches is available in all git commands.

Suggested further reading:

- [Git: Difficulty Getting Existing Git Repository to Track New Bare Remote Repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60357692/git-difficulty-getting-existing-git-repository-to-track-new-bare-remote-reposit)

*FYI: all commands tested with git V2.32 on Windows.*

Answer (score 1):

`--set-upstream` is not just about [`git branch -u`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-branch#Documentation/git-branch.txt---set-upstream) or [`git push -u`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-push#Documentation/git-push.txt--u).

You also have [`git fetch --set-upstream`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-fetch#Documentation/git-fetch.txt---set-upstream) and [`git pull --set-upstream`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-pull#Documentation/git-pull.txt---set-upstream).

> If the remote is fetched successfully, add upstream (tracking) reference, used by argument-less `git pull` and other commands

It will set:

- `branch.<name>.remote`
- `branch.<name>.merge`

That will allow `git push` to know *where* to push, and *to* which remote branch to push to.

But: "[`git fetch --set-upstream`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/dcaf17c75d925531ba399a211e63664784d96821/Documentation/fetch-options.txt#L217)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-fetch#Documentation/git-fetch.txt---set-upstream))</sup> did not check if there is a current branch, leading to a **segfault** when it is run on a **[detached HEAD](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3965714/6309)**, which has been corrected with Git 2.35 (Q1 2022).

See [commit 17baeaf](https://github.com/git/git/commit/17baeaf82db5581f451c876320bf9719d72da675) (07 Dec 2021) by [Ævar Arnfjörð Bjarmason (`avar`)](https://github.com/avar).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit dcaf17c](https://github.com/git/git/commit/dcaf17c75d925531ba399a211e63664784d96821), 22 Dec 2021)</sup>

> ### [`pull, fetch`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/17baeaf82db5581f451c876320bf9719d72da675): fix segfault in --set-upstream option
>
> <sup>Reported-by: Clemens Fruhwirth</sup>
> <sup>Reported-by: Jan Pokorný</sup>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Ævar Arnfjörð Bjarmason</sup>

> Fix a segfault in the `--set-upstream` option added in [24bc1a1](https://github.com/git/git/commit/24bc1a129260eaf713c87f087f28883fe18891b5) (pull, 2019-08-19, Git v2.24.0-rc0 -- [merge](https://github.com/git/git/commit/94373946614f864bdcd5e0cb72e360edbed1c77f) listed in [batch #2](https://github.com/git/git/commit/f1d4a28250629ae469fc5dd59ab843cb2fd68e12)) (pull, fetch: [`add`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/17baeaf82db5581f451c876320bf9719d72da675/Documentation/git-add.txt)<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-add))</sup> `--set-upstream` option, 2019-08-19) added in v2.24.0.
>
> The code added there did not do the same checking we do for "[`git branch`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/17baeaf82db5581f451c876320bf9719d72da675/Documentation/git-branch.txt)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-branch))</sup> itself since [8efb889](https://github.com/git/git/commit/8efb8899cfe866dddb3659b9e0a94232161db65e) ("`branch`: segfault fixes and validation", 2013-02-23, Git v1.8.3-rc0 -- [merge](https://github.com/git/git/commit/42e129f47af19c7623bac39f20c74b4d349a81f9) listed in [batch #2](https://github.com/git/git/commit/2bba2f0e6542d541e9f27653d8c9d5fc8d0e679c)), which in turn fixed the same sort of segfault I'm fixing now in "[`git branch --set-upstream-to`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/17baeaf82db5581f451c876320bf9719d72da675/Documentation/git-branch.txt#L233)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-branch#Documentation/git-branch.txt---set-upstream-toltupstreamgt))</sup>, see [6183d82](https://github.com/git/git/commit/6183d826ba62ec94ccfcb8f6e3b8d43e3e338703) ("`branch`: introduce `--set-upstream-to`", 2012-08-20, Git v1.8.0-rc0 -- [merge](https://github.com/git/git/commit/83ce1764496d90a5ef45b0a109ab5fc222a62199) listed in [batch #5](https://github.com/git/git/commit/682ce8bb37414afe87515123fc6c26f21dd35b15)).
>
> The warning message I'm adding here is an amalgamation of the error added for "`git branch`" in [8efb889](https://github.com/git/git/commit/8efb8899cfe866dddb3659b9e0a94232161db65e), and the error output `install_branch_config()` itself emits, i.e.
> it trims "`refs/heads/`" from the name and says "`branch X on remote`", not "`branch refs/heads/X on remote`".

New warning:

```
could not set upstream of HEAD to 'X' from 'X' 
when it does not point to any branch
```

> I think it would make more sense to simply `die()` here, but in the other checks for `--set-upstream` added in [24bc1a1](https://github.com/git/git/commit/24bc1a129260eaf713c87f087f28883fe18891b5), we issue a warning() instead.
> Let's do the same here for consistency for now.
>
> There was an earlier submitted alternate way of fixing this [in this thread](https://lore.kernel.org/git/20210706162238.575988-1-clemens@endorphin.org/), due to that patch breaking threading with the original report at [this thread](https://lore.kernel.org/git/CAG6gW_uHhfNiHGQDgGmb1byMqBA7xa8kuH1mP-wAPEe5Tmi2Ew@mail.gmail.com/).
> I didn't notice it before authoring this version.
> I think the more detailed warning message here is better, and we should also have tests for this behavior.
>
> The `--no-rebase` option to "[`git pull`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/17baeaf82db5581f451c876320bf9719d72da675/Documentation/git-pull.txt)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-pull))</sup> is needed as of the recently merged [7d0daf3](https://github.com/git/git/commit/7d0daf3f12f87799a3b3f524933ef6c15d1f28c3) ("Merge branch 'en/pull-conflicting-options'", 2021-08-30, Git v2.34.0-rc0 -- [merge](https://github.com/git/git/commit/7d0daf3f12f87799a3b3f524933ef6c15d1f28c3) listed in [batch #2](https://github.com/git/git/commit/6c40894d2466d4e7fddc047a05116aa9d14712ee)).