# In Git How to Refer to Current Branch without using its full name?

Tags: git

Is there a way to refer to the current branch during git push origin instead of using full name like:

```
git push origin myBranch
```

I was thinking of linux "." like operator to refer to current branch without having to use its full name.

Comment: If your local branch is tracking a remote one, then you can do just `git push`

Comment: When pushing, I think you can just do `git push`. Edit: Oops, barely ninja'd.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get the current branch name in Git?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6245570/how-to-get-the-current-branch-name-in-git)

Comment: If you do git status and you see something like (Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/myBranch'), then all you need to do is git push

Answer (score 2):

Do this:

```
git branch --set-upstream-to origin/myBranch
```

Then you can just do

```
git push
```

From the [man page](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-branch.html):

> **--set-upstream-to=<upstream>**
>   Set up <branchname>'s tracking information so <upstream> is considered <branchname>'s upstream branch. If no <branchname> is specified, then it defaults to the current branch.

See this [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18032014/2089675) for details

Comment: Thanks, could you please explain what --set-upstream-to does?

Comment: @GoldenSugar: JFYI, you can `git branch --help`

Comment: It's `--set-upstream`, not `--set-upstream-to`. At least in git 2.11.0

Comment: @SergioTulentsev, using git 2.12.0, the option is `set-upstream-to`. What version of git do you have?

Comment: @SergioTulentsev, didn't refresh :p

Comment: Note that the user must have Git version 2.0 or above and/or have configured `push.default` to `simple` *and* not have other special situations going on. (The situation is a bit complicated: 2.0-or-later *defaults* to a `push.default` of `simple`, but Git 1.9 defaults to `matching`; and there are ways to override all these settings.)

Comment: @SergioTulentsev: `--set-upstream` is the old option, `--set-upstream-to` is the new preferred option (new in Git 1.8.0). The key difference between them is the way the upstream-to-set and the branch-whose-upstream-is-to-be-set are specified: people were always getting it backwards in Git 1.7.x.