# Why doesn’t git show that I’m ahead of origin?

Tags: git

**Ubuntu 16.04**

I know that I have organized a remote repository.

I can execute:

```
git add .
git commit -am "Savepoint"
```

Then I can check:

```
michael@Thinkpad:~/PycharmProjects/photoarchive_2$ git status
On branch master
nothing to commit, working directory clean
```

But I know that I'm ahead of origin.

I execute:

```
git push origin master
```

And now I can see my commit at the remote repository.

I expect git to show me the information like:

```
Your branch is ahead of 'origin/master' by 3 commits.
```

Could you tell me there is no such information shown?

ADDED LATER:

```
git show-branch -a
* [master] Started working with Image
 ! [origin/master] Started working with Image
--
*+ [master] Started working with Image
```

Comment: can you try `git branch -vv` to check whether you're tracking the remote branch or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you need to track the remote branch?

```
$ git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/master master
```

See [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18031946/what-does-set-upstream-do) for details about `--set-upstream`. In short, it tells git what remote branch you push the local one to.

Comment: Tried git branch -vv
* master 4995aeb Started working with Image So, it is the correct branch. And the only one.

Comment: Pardon. Maybe this is not the only one branch. I edited my question. Please, have a look at it (at the bottom of the question).

Comment: Even if your `master` is the only branch, you have only one `origin` remote and there’s also a `master` branch there, git doesn’t necessarily know that you wish to push your `master` to `origin/master`, so you have to tell it by using `--set-upstream` (or by adding `-t` when checking the remote branch out).