# How to create Github repository from a site that's already live

Tags: git, github, web-deployment

I'm having some issues using Git.

I already have a live site hosted on a Digital Ocean droplet. I'd like to push my code to a github repo, and from then do all my development locally. I would push my local code to github and then do updates to the live site by pulling from github.

However, I'm having some trouble getting off the ground.

I already have the repo created and I did a quick `git init` on the project. I've added the files, made a commit, and then added the repo. However, when I run `git push` I get this:

```
fatal: The current branch master has no upstream branch.
To push the current branch and set the remote as upstream, use

    git push --set-upstream github master
```

So, I ran `git push --set-upstream github master`. It gave me this error:

```
 ! [rejected]        master -> master (fetch first)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/WordsofDefiance/davidaccomazzo.com.git'
hint: Updates were rejected because the remote contains work that you do
hint: not have locally. This is usually caused by another repository pushing
hint: to the same ref. You may want to first integrate the remote changes
hint: (e.g., 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
```

Can anyone help me create this initial commit to the repo? I'm imagine I'm missing something super basic.

EDIT: I ended up using `--force` when pushing, and it worked. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well this is a stupid answer but, the repository you are using doesn't seem to exist, did you created it ?

If so and it's not public, is it really empty ? A git push --force might be of some use.

Comment: It is in fact a private repo. Does that change anything?

Comment: That would generate a different error.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your first question about the upstream error, this is because in order to run `git push` without any other arguments, you need to have a default remote branch set. This is so that git knows where to send your code. By setting the upstream to `github master`, you are essentially telling git to run `git push github master` whenever you run `git push`. There's a more detailed answer about how it works [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18031946/what-does-set-upstream-do).

As for your second question, silmari may be correct that your remote repository (on GitHub) is not actually empty. This could have happened if you chose to add a license file (e.g. MIT) or a `.gitignore` file when initially setting up the repository on GitHub. In that case, GitHub created a commit for you, which you do not have locally, which is where the conflict arose.

So what I would do first is look at the commit history of your GitHub repo, and see if there are any commits there that you don't have locally. Because you've already made a commit locally, you may have to do a [git rebase](https://blog.algolia.com/master-git-rebase/) with your remote branch in order to "clean up" your local history, and be able to push (without resorting to a force push).

Again, much of this is a guess on my part. I hope it helps.

Comment: I ended up doing a `git push --force` and setting the upstream master and it worked. Looks like I can make commits now, no problem. Thanks for your help.