# git, use commands on branch that is being used

Tags: git

Lets say that I have this:

```
C:\project (release/FASE_F2_E4_V3)
λ git pull origin release/FASE_F2_E4_V3
```

Is there a way to `pull`, `push` or execute a git comand without specifying the actual branch?

I mean, something like:

```
git pull origin (actual_branch)
```

and not

```
git pull origin a_very_long_name_of_the_branch
```

Edit:

this is what I get with `git pull` and git the branch explicit:

[image]

Comment: `git pull` without any additional arguments pulls the current branch, `release/FASE_F2_E4_V3` in this case.

Answer (score 1):

For `push` you want:

> git config --global push.default current

If you are on your local `release/FASE_F2_E4_V3` branch running `git push` will push to the origin branch of the same name.

`pull` should already behave like this; pulling when on `release/FASE_F2_E4_V3` will pull from `origin release/FASE_F2_E4_V3,` assuming you created your local branch from that.

If you want your local `release/FASE_F2_E4_V3` to map to a longer-named branch on the remote then you do indeed have to follow the set-upstream-to command as per your question.

Answer (score 0):

If you run `git pull`, the branch that is currently checked out will be pulled.

If you want to pull a branch without specifying name in `git pull`, you will have to checkout that particular branch.

For example, you have currently checked out branch `A` and you want to pull branch `B` then first checkout branch `B` and the run `git pull`.

```
git checkout B
git pull
```

After you edit the question:

In the image you have posted, it says to run `git pull` you should have an upstream branch i.e set the default remote branch for the current local branch so that `git pull` understands which branch to pull from.

As shown in the image, run the below command to set an upstream:

`git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/<branch> release/FASE_F2_E4_V3`

To learn more about `--set-upstream`, you might want to read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18031946/what-does-set-upstream-do).

Comment: Same with `push`? I thought that `git pull` without branch would pull every branch that I had. Lol. I don't get it, I will edit the question with a image of both cases

Comment: Yes, same with `push`.