# Pycharm suggesting to push code in new Gitlab branch with the old name of my local branch

Tags: pycharm

I had a local git branch of my project called `my_branch`.

I pushed the branch on Gitlab, so its name on Gitlab was `my_branch`.

Then I renamed the local branch as `my_branch_2` via Pycharm bottom-left-located wizard (`branch name > rename ...`), and I also renamed it on Gitlab, via browser UI.

Now, in Pycharm, every time I `VCS > Git > Push...`, Pycharm suggests me to push the code into a new branch called `my_branch` as default.

In few words, in the left frame of window "Push commits to my_project", I have

> my_branch_2 -> origin: my_branch (new!)

but what I want is

> my_branch_2 -> origin: my_branch_2

How can I fix things in order to get it?

Comment: You simply need to change your local branch's upstream pointer. Does this answer your question? [What does '--set-upstream' do?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18031946/184546)

Comment: This link is probably a little better: [Make an existing Git branch track a remote branch?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/520650/184546)

Comment: Hi, thanks for the suggestions, however, those thread does not answer my question since the simplest solution I needed deals with pycharm and not with git commands via command line.

Comment: Just a thought...When I first started using Git, like you, I also preferred to only use my client GUI rather than the command line. But I later learned that there are many things you can only do from the command line, and the feedback you get from the command line is far superior than most GUIs. Once I got more comfortable with the command line my Git experience greatly increased, and now I find it one of the most enjoyable parts of day to day coding. If I could go back in time I would have recommended to myself to use the command line from the beginning. (And buy bitcoin.)

Comment: Thanks for sharing your experience :) I will try to run git from command line rather than from GUIs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED

By accessing the Pycharm bottom-left-located wizard (branch name > rename ...) I renamed the **remote** branch `my_branch` as `my_branch_2`, and now in the window "Push commits to my_project" I get:

> my_branch_2 -> origin: my_branch_2

In conclusion, **there was no need to touch Gitlab nor to run commands via command line**, it was sufficient to rename both the local and the remote branches from the Pycharm bottom-left-located wizard.