# How to undo configuration of how the remote repository's branch connects to the local branch?

Tags: git

I created a local repository and I typed:

```
git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/master
```

to set up the configuration of how the remote repository's branch connects to the local branch.

```
git push
```

works fine.

If I enter:

```
git config --get-regex branch.master
```

I get:

```
branch.master.remote origin
branch.master.merge refs/heads/master
```

which is what git added to the configuration using:

```
git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/master
```

But it turned out that the above command is not necessary.
Is that correct?

Other repositories that I created with the same commands and without the above command seem to work fine and they push to the remote without any issues.

Since I think that that configuration is not needed, how do I remove the configuration entries from the affected local repository?

Here are the commands that I used to create all the local repositories (I also used the above command for the afflicted repository):

```
git init
git add .
git commit -m "Initial commit"
git remote add origin https://...git
Git pull origin master --allow-unrelated-histories
git push origin master
```

Regards,
sp2012

Comment: What do you mean by "not necessary"? See [Why do I have to "git push --set-upstream origin <branch>"?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37770467/1256452) and related questions. Use `git branch --unset-upstream` to remove an upstream setting (or two `git config` commands, but one `git branch` is easier).

Comment: Hello torek. Thank you for your comment. By "not necessary", I meant that the repository worked fine, just other repositories where I didn't use the command git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/master. Git branch --unset-upstream worked fine by the way and the entries are now removed from my configuration. By the way, I am new to git, so I don't understand a lot about git.

Comment: It's a question basically of whether you want to be able to say `git pull`. I never do so I don't usually need an upstream on my branches. You might want to read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18031946/what-does-set-upstream-do.

Comment: And there is my https://www.biteinteractive.com/picturing-git-conceptions-and-misconceptions/ which talks about saying `git push`. Again, I never really care whether I can say this so I don't usually need an upstream. I'm perfectly happy saying `git push origin @` when I push.

Answer (score 0):

> Other repositories that I created with the same commands and without the above command seem to work fine and they push to the remote without any issues.

If you have created them with `git clone`, that command would have clone and checkout the default remote branch, setting the upstream branch in the process.
In that case, no need for [`git branch -u`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2286030/6309).

In your case, after a `git init`, a `git push origin master` would work, but would not set any [upstream tracking reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6244487/6309).

That is why I detailed in "[Why do I need to explicitly push a new branch?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17096880/6309)" that the right command is, for the first push:

```
git push -u origin master
```

That would push *and* do the `git branch --set-upstream-to` for you.

The next push would be  simple `git push`.