# zsh: number expected while using `git push --set-upstream` command

Tags: git, macos, zsh, upstream-branch, upstream

I am getting `zsh: number expected` whenever I`m running the following command:-

**Command** - `git push --set-upstream origin branch_name`

I`m using Oh My Zsh as my terminal in MacBook Pro with M1 chip.

I even tried another command like `git push -u origin my_branch`, but this also not working giving out the same error message `zsh: number expected`

More on use of --set-upstream [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18031946/what-does-set-upstream-do) & why do we need to do it all the time is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6089294/why-do-i-need-to-do-set-upstream-all-the-time).

Comment: I can't reproduce it with a branch named either `branch_name` or `my_branch`. Perhaps the message comes from one of your [git hooks](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks)? Did you try to temporarily [disable your hooks](https://gist.github.com/MrSwed/4bb4e0a8c2a2f35827e6d9b410642582)?

Comment: Have you tried put any library inside the brackets, for instance - `git push --set-upstream origin resampling(asyncio)`

Comment: You would have to quote the last argument, i.e. `'resampling(asyncio)'`, otherwise zsh takes it as filename generation flags.

Comment: Alright, I`ll try that out too.
Thank you for your suggestion 

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got the solution for this issue:

Earlier I was running `git push --set-upstream origin branch_name`, with some library name in the branch name within the brackets.

For instance:
`git push --set-upstream origin resampling(asyncio)`

What I found out is, `()` usually treats the content somehow differently.

And I was having **zsh: number expected** error as it was expecting a version number for the mentioned library.

To resolve this, I made a new branch and removed `()` from the branch name & the same command `git push --set-upstream origin branch_name` worked fine.

Hope this answer would be helpful for the community.