# Is it possible to set your git pull <remote_master> so that you can just write git pull in the future and it pulls this <remote_master>?

Tags: git, terminal

I am working on a git repository that has branches constantly being merged into it, and I would like to somehow sync

```
git pull <remote_master>
```

So that in the future I just need to execute

```
git pull
```

And it will execute git pull from this `<remote_master>` ; is this possible?

I am on a Linux machine if it makes any difference.

***Further to the comments below***

When I try the solution proposed, I get the following error:

```
error: the requested upstream branch 'git@github.com:xxx/xxx.git' does not exist
hint: 
hint: If you are planning on basing your work on an upstream
hint: branch that already exists at the remote, you may need to
hint: run "git fetch" to retrieve it.
hint: 
hint: If you are planning to push out a new local branch that
hint: will track its remote counterpart, you may want to use
hint: "git push -u" to set the upstream config as you push.
```

Here is what my `git branch` looks like:

```
(jobserveee) patrick@patrick-lp:~/work/jobserve$ git branch
  ED-3312_adding_captureTimestamp_to_marketData_files
  ED-3312_adding_capture_timestamp_to_quote_and_trade_tables_in_MD_files
  ED-4785_Investigate_security_type_for_TSE_data_pre-2015
  ED-4931_stop_updating_rawDataFile_statuses_after_pass1_has_run
  ED-4931_stop_updating_rawDataFile_statuses_after_pass1_has_run3
* master
```

I am trying to sync the `master` branch with a remote branch (I won't paste it here as I'm not sure I am allowed), but basically the way I get my remote branch URL is: in the remote repository I click `code` -> `SSH` and I copy the URL.

Then I execute

```
git branch --set-upstream-to <paste_the_URL_I_described_above>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with:

```bash
git switch <branch to sync>
git branch --set-upstream-to origin <branch to sync>
```

This sets the default remote branch for the current local branch, as perfectly explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18031946/what-does-set-upstream-do).

Comment: Hmmm it says that branch doesn't exist for some reason

Comment: @Patrick_Chong: Presumably that means the upstream you're trying to set, e.g., `origin/br-abc`, does not exist in your repository yet. If branch `br-abc` does exist on `origin`, run `git fetch origin` now to have your Git call up the Git software over at `origin` and see that they have a `br-abc`, so that your Git creates your `origin/br-abc`. If *they* don't have a `br-abc` yet either, create one there, *then* run `git fetch`, or do all of that at once with `git push -u`.

Comment: Davide, for the second command when you say `<branch to sync>` is the URL for my remote branch? Or do I replace `origin` with my remote branch?

Comment: Sorry Patrick for the unclear answer. `<branch to sync>` is the name of the branch, such as `main` or `develop`.

Comment: So I don't enter the remote branch anywhere?

Comment: The branch you specify in `git switch` is local, since it is selected from the local set of branches. Instead, the branch you set in `git branch --set-upstream-to origin <branch to sync>` is remote, since you have prepended the name of the branch with `origin`.

Comment: Thanks Davide, it is all clear now. I am still struggling a bit with torek's answer, as I am still getting `does not exist` issue. What does he mean by " `origin/br-abc` does not exist in my repository"- does he mean my local repository? 
I am also not sure what `origin` refers to- is this the name of m local branch I am trying to sync with the remote branch?

Comment: `origin` is the name of your remote (a nice-looking name in place of the bare URL). In general, if you specify just the name of a branch it is referred to local environment; instead, if you specify also origin at the side of the branch name it refers to the branch on remote repository. In order to do the operations I gave, first ensure that both the local and the remote branches exist; if not, just create them.

Comment: Hi Davide, thank you for the explanation it is extremely helpful. I have tried it, but I still get the same `does not exist` error. I have added to my question above- would you kindly have a look? Thanks!

Comment: First of all, git suggests you to run `git fetch` because your local environment may not know yet that the target remote branch exists.
`<branch to sync>` is the name of the branch, like 'main' or 'develop', not a URL. Remember to prepend the keyword `origin` like in my answer.
git suggests to use the flag -u, but it is just the shorthand for --set-upstream-to.

Comment: Thanks Davide, again extremely helpful comment! - I have run a `git fetch` and it produces `* branch                HEAD       -> FETCH_HEAD`. 
I then run `git branch --set-upstream-to origin master` (as the name of the remote branch I would like to sync is "master"). 

But again I get the error that `requested branch origin does not exist`

Comment: Ok. Try with replacing the space between `origin` and the branch name with a forward slash `/`. So you have for instance:
`git switch <branch>`
`git branch --set-upstream-to origin/<branch>`
Try listing the remotes you have through the command: `git remote`

Comment: You can also use this notation: `git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/<branch> <branch>`