# How to mirror a Github repository and continue to push updates

Tags: github, repository

I am planning to pull a repository on Github into my private Gitlab and continue to push my own updates to Gitlab while frequently pulling changes from the upstream repository on Github. Please can someone show me the steps and commands. I am not sure how to do it. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi you can create multiple origins to point to Github and Gitlab. These SO threads should help you out.

[Can a project have multiple origins?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11690709/can-a-project-have-multiple-origins)

[pull/push from multiple remote locations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/849308/pull-push-from-multiple-remote-locations)

UPDATE:

Yes, you will have to add remotes for both Github and Gitlab in your local copy.

Then pull the changes from Github and handle any merge issues, then checkin locally and push to Gitlab.

Comment: Kalpana, thanks, I am not sure how does it solve my question. I have a project that I cloned form Github, made changes and checked the code into my private Gitlab. Now the developers pushed changes to Github which I want to pull into my Gitlab. Do you mean the only way to merge the code from Gihub onto my local repo and push to the remote Gitlab repo?

Comment: Ok I will try it and report back here. Thanks