# Git: How to remove remote origin for deleted repo?

Tags: git, github

I am trying to push to my remote repository on Github, but I keep receiving the following error (from VS Code, same error in Github Desktop):

```
> git push -u origin main
remote: Repository not found.
fatal: repository 'https://github.com/<user>/<deleted-repository>/' not found
```

The error says the repository is not found, which is true because it has been **deleted**.

After using:

```
$ git remote add origin https://github.com/<user>/<new-existing-repository.git>
```

My remotes currently look like:

```
git remote -v
origin  https://github.com/<user>/<deleted-repository.git> (fetch)
origin  https://github.com/<user>/<deleted-repository.git> (push)
origin  https://github.com/<user>/<new-existing-repository.git> (push)
```

I have tried:

```
git remote remove origin
```

which removes the new remote. I have also tried

> git remote remove <https://github.com/<user>/<deleted-repository.git>

Neither works.

I also have noticed that for my new remote I only have "(push)", whereas the other one has both "(fetch)" and "(push)".

Edit:

I removed the new remote and tried the following:

```
$ git remote -v
origin  https://github.com/<user>/<deleted-repository.git> (fetch)
origin  https://github.com/<user>/<deleted-repository.git> (push)

$ git remote remove origin
fatal: No such remote: 'origin'

$ git remote set-url --delete origin https://github.com/<user>/<deleted-repository.git>
fatal: No such remote 'origin'

$ git remote set-url origin https://github.com/<user>/<new-existing-repository.git>
fatal: No such remote 'origin'
```

Any insight into this issue would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: what happens if you do `git remote remove origin` again **after** it removes the new repo?

Comment: Likely duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11690709/can-a-project-have-multiple-origins

Answer (score 0):

Say

```
git remote set-url --delete origin https://github.com/<user>/<deleted-repository.git>
```

That will delete the deleted origin.

But I would also suggest that you delete the other origin too and start over. You evidently added the second origin in an incorrect manner.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
git remote set-url origin https://github.com/<user>/<new-existing-repository.git>
```

it should remove old url and will add new one.

since you deleted origin by using

```
git remote remove origin
```

now if you will check by

```
git remote -v
```

It won’t return anything

You can simply add new url by

```
git remote add origin https://github.com/<user>/<new-existing-repository.git>
```