# Git flow track - already exists

Tags: git, git-flow

I am learning GIT (with Git Flow) and I know its not good to use StackOverflow instead of a book.

I am involved in a project. There are two feature  branches named F1 and F2 maintained by groups G1 and G2. Assume F1 depends on F2 and G1 has `published` its branch using `git flow feature publish F1`.

Now G2 needs to track F1 and well may be do a re-base on top of F1 from time to time. For this I red that we need to use `git flow track`

So I (of G2) used some thing like this

```
git flow feature checkout F2
git flow feature track F1
```

But Git is saying the following:

```
Branch 'feature/F1' already exists. Pick another name.
```

Then I tried a name that didn't and hoped it will at some point ask me for the branch that needs to be tracked. But then I got this message.

```
git flow feature track F1_track
Branch 'origin/feature/F1_track' does not exist and is required.
```

Am I doing some thing silly? Could it be an issue with my installation?

I believe you understand what I am trying to do, could you please help me out in the issue.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you consider the code of [`git flow feature track`](https://github.com/nvie/gitflow/blob/develop/git-flow-feature#L406-L424), all that it does is creating a local branch tracking a remote one.

If you already have a local feature/F1 branch, check that it does track origin/feature/F1 with [`git branch -av`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7733266/6309):

- if it does, you have nothing to do
- if it doesn't, you can [set the tracking relationship yourself](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2286030/6309)
  `git branch -u origin/feature/F1 feature/F1`

Comment: Now it makes sense, so `tracking` means we make a local `F1` feature that tracks a remote `F1` feature. If we wan't to fetch the changes done to the F1 after checking out F2 we could use `rebase ` like (on F2) `git rebase feature/F1`. It worked!