# Git push not creating remote branch, pushing to master

Tags: git, push, git-push

I'm having an issue where I'm trying to push a local branch to a remote branch so that I can then create a pull request into master. I'm using:

`git push origin brachname`

This seems to fail, and instead is pushing to the master remote branch (which isn't great).
If I reference the local and remote branches explicitly (ie: branchname:branchname) it works fine. It seems that either I have something off with my git config, or there's something wrong with the way I'm creating my local branches.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Push a new local branch to a remote Git repo and track it too](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2765421/push-a-new-local-branch-to-a-remote-git-repo-and-track-it-too)

Comment: The command looks just fine. So how _do_ you create your local branches?

Comment: Which branch does it think it's tracking? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/171550/find-out-which-remote-branch-a-local-branch-is-tracking

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you are on the **`master`** branch and trying to push it to another branch.

#### How to be able to push to different branch name?

**Set/Update the tracking branch**

git < 1.8:
`git branch --set-upstream branch_name remote/branch_name`

git > 1.8:
`git branch branch_name --set-upstream-to remote/branch_name`

Your current tracking information is inside your `.git/config` file

---

**Create a new branch with the desired name**

```
git checkout -b <new_branch>
git push origin <new_branch>
```

git will push to the remote branch your current branch name (assuming you did not changed the tracking branch)

---

**Renaming the branch (so the tracking branch will be updated too)**

Or you can use the -u switch:
`git branch branch_name -u remote/branch_name`

---

Comment: I'm using `--set-upstream` with current Git versions.

Comment: It always worked for me and it is also what Git itself suggests when you don't have any upstream set.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below

```
 git push -u origin <branch_name>
```

If you have permission to push a local branch onto remote repo, it should go through

Comment: If you would have read the question this is exactly what he did (line 2 in the question)

Comment: Doesn't look like he set the upstream ?

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar problem after renaming a local instance of a new and recently pulled branch from `develop` to `origin-develop`.  The branch was fetched from the remote repo `origin`.

After the rename, a generic push commands I gave would always try to push to `origin/master`.  i.e.,

```
$ git push
To github.com:<USER>/<REPO>.git
 ! [rejected]        master -> master (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 'github.com:<USER>/<REPO>.git'
```

I tried using `git branch origin develop`, but that didn't fix the problem. Instead, I got the error

```
$ git push origin develop
error: src refspec develop does not match any
error: failed to push some refs to 'github.com:<USER>/<REPO>.git'
```

Using the command `git remote show origin` allowed me to see that the while the local branch `origin-develop` was set up correctly for pulling (presumably because I created the local branch using the pull command), it was missing the push setting.

```
Local branches configured for 'git pull':
<snip>
    origin-develop                      merges with remote develop
<snip>
 Local refs configured for 'git push':
<snip>
```

I was able to fix my problem by using the command

```
git push origin origin-develop:develop
```

This worked, but I don't consider it *solved* because I have to use this command every time I want to push this branch to the remote.  If I just use `git push` I get the `! [rejected]        master -> master (non-fast-forward)` error.

My understanding is that my `pull` command set up the remote for pulling, but not pushing.  Because no remote push was defined, it defaulted to pushing to `master`.

What I don't understand is how to permanently change my configuration so that `git push` works as expected.  I've tried using `git branch -u` , but get the same behavior (i.e. can't push).  I wonder if somehow the push `-all` option is now the default and the error message is independent of the branch `origin-develop`.