# Push specific commit on the remote branch tracking the current branch

Tags: git, push

This question shows how to push up to a commit to the master branch (eg all parent commits of the specific commit):

[How can I pushing specific commit to a remote, and not the previous commits?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3230074/git-pushing-specific-commit)

The answer is :

```
git push <remotename> <commit SHA>:<remotebranchname>
```

so you can use `git push origin <commit SHA>:master`

However, I would like to automatically push that commit to the matching remote branch.

I can't just use `git push <remotename> "<commit SHA>:$(git branch)"` because git branch returns the local branches, I would like to have the matching remote branch (eg for example you can map the local master `branch` to map to the remote `prod` branch). I would like to take that into account.

Comment: Your understanding of git seems conflicted to me. What you are trying to do, essentially pushing individual commits from a branch to the remote, will not work if some commits in the interim are missing. Instead, you can update the branch directly using `git push origin branchname`, or create a fresh one using `git push origin local_branch:new_remote_branch`.

Comment: I clearly understand git. My use case is that I want to publish only up to a specific commit and not further (because I might change those commits in the future). I created a function that does basically `git push origin <commit SHA>:master` , where commit sha is a parameter. However, I'm now not on the master branch, so I would like my function to automatically push to the right remote tracking branch

Answer (score 0):

Due to how Git works, a commit does not clearly belong to a branch. Branches are just pointers to commits that are located somewhere in the global history tree, so when you want to push a certain commit individually to a remote branch, that commit does not say anything about which branch you could possibly mean.

The only thing you can do it is to find branches where the commit is contained on, using `git branch --contains`. If that only returns one branch, then you’re in luck and everything is clear but the command may return multiple branches if the commit is reachable by multiple branches. For everything else, like the tracking branch, you would have to look at your repository’s configuration.

However, your workflow seems a bit weird to me. If you keep wanting to push an older commit instead of your current branch, then what you should really do is to make a new branch. Have one branch which matches the remote one which you then can just push; and have one other branch that’s ahead of that branch where your development happens. And whenever you want to update the remote, you update your local branch that matches the remote and then just push that branch.

So your history would look like this:

```
              prod               master
               ↓                   ↓
* -- * -- * -- * -- * -- * -- * -- *
```

And you could just push `prod` using `git push origin prod` and make that resolve whatever remote tracking branch actually is behind.

Comment: > However, your workflow seems a bit weird to me. : In my case what I want is to be able to push only commits that I have looked twice, so that I'm sure I don't commit something that I shouldn't be commiting (unnecessary code, ...). That's why I'm sometimes comitting only up to one commit.

Comment: My question can be simplified a lot : git branch returns the current local branch. However, I would like to get the remote branch that tracks the current branch using the command line (eg not looking into ~/.git/config

Comment: Even if you want to push one commit at a time, use a branch to do it. It gets simpler that way, and also a lot more clear.

Comment: I'm using tig so pushing one commit is just one keystroke, it's just that my binding doesn't work because the branch name is incorrect. Creating a branch in my use case would be overkill

Comment: I'm going to use http://stackoverflow.com/questions/171550/find-out-which-remote-branch-a-local-branch-is-tracking