# Git - show remote name of remote branch

Tags: git, shell

Is there a Git command to show the remote name of a remote branch?

Currently I stick with extracting the remote name from a remote branch ref using shell utils like ...

```
$ echo "remote-name/branch-name" | sed -r 's;^([^/]+)/.*;\1;'
remote-name
```

sometimes passing it through for validation purposes

```
$ git rev-parse --symbolic-full-name "remote-name/branch-name" | ...
```

I wonder if there's a builtin command like.

```
$ git wanted-command [wanted options] "remote-name/branch-name"
remote-name
```

I've looked though the manpages of `rev-parse`, `remote` and `ls-remote`.

Comment: `git branch -av` should do it

Comment: No, it shows all branches including their tracking (remote) branches (if they have one). I'd like to get the remote name (like "origin") using an official GIt command, not by parsing branch names.

Comment: you're right. my bad...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not the prettiest solution but I think it should generally work. (I feel like there should be a better way but I can't think of it at the moment.)

```
symref=$(git symbolic-ref --short HEAD)
git config --local "branch.$symref.remote"
```

And, for completeness and to sum-up some of the comments below, the name of the tracking branch on the remote (which may not be the same as the name remote ref in the local repository) is available from `branch.$symref.merge`.

Comment: This is the correct way.  Note, however, that if the output of the above is `.`, the "remote" is your own local repository, i.e., your local branch `foo` may be "tracking" your own local branch `master`  for instance.  Also, if you want to know what the branch's name is *on the remote* that's in `branch.$symref.name`, but due to the way the `fetch =` line works, the local remote-tracking branch might have some other name (but this is rare, possibly to the point of non-existence, it's merely *possible*).

Comment: @torek Can you explain that final bit again (re: `fetch =`)?

Comment: OK: normally if you look at a remote like `origin` (in .git/config) you'll see: `fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*`.  This is how their `master` becomes your `origin/master`, the two `*`s are matched up.  But if you find instead `fetch = +refs/heads/master:refs/remotes/origin/xyzzy`, *their* `master` becomes *your* `origin/xyzzy`.  If you want to track theirs, you should have `branch.master.remote = origin` but `branch.master.merge = master` even though you're tracking `origin/xyzzy`.  This is a historical accident, of sorts.

Comment: (ran out of room) The `merge` line lists the branch name as it's known in *their* repo, so to find how the branch is known in your own repo, you must map it through the `fetch =` line(s) associated with the remote.  It's pretty crazy to have the output of that mapping be anything other than `origin/master`, but it's allowed.  I'm not actually sure which parts of git behave well or poorly if you do something this crazy, though.

Comment: @torek Ah, thanks. Yeah, specific `fetch` refs are weird. One more question though. What sets `branch.$symref.name` and where is that documented? I don't see it anywhere.

Comment: `branch.$ref.name`?  Haven't seen that one.  `git config` lists `.description`, `.mergeOptions`, etc, but not `.name` ...

Comment: @torek I don't see it either but you mentioned it `Also, if you want to know what the branch's name is on the remote that's in branch.$symref.name`. Though... following the rest of the comment I see that you probably meant `branch.$symref.merge` there in the first place.

Comment: Oh.  Right, that should say `merge`, not `name`.  Typo (more of a think-o)!  Can't edit now, alas.

Answer (score 2):

If instead of the remote reference, you started with a *local* reference, you could use [`git for-each-ref`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-for-each-ref) with the `%(upstream:remotename)` format.

I use this together with `git symbolic-ref -q HEAD` to get the remote name for the current checkout:

```sh
remote=$(git for-each-ref --format='%(upstream:remotename)' "$(git symbolic-ref -q HEAD)")
```

Demo with the most common remote:

```
% git for-each-ref --format='%(upstream:remotename)' "$(git symbolic-ref -q HEAD)" 
origin
```