# git command works in console but not as alias

Tags: git, bash

The following command works in the console:

```
 git reset --soft `git rev-parse --abbrev-ref --symbolic-full-name @{u}` && git commit --edit -m "$(git log --format=%B --reverse HEAD..HEAD@{1})"
```

It is meant to squash the unpushed commits into one and give a chance to edit the message. See [Find out which remote branch a local branch is tracking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/171550/find-out-which-remote-branch-a-local-branch-is-tracking) and [Squash my last X commits together using Git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5189560/squash-my-last-x-commits-together-using-git) for more details.

However the following alias fails:

```
squash-uncomited = reset --soft `git rev-parse --abbrev-ref --symbolic-full-name @{u}` && git commit --edit -m "$(git log --format=%B --reverse HEAD..HEAD@{1})"
```

> ✗ git squash-uncomited error: unknown option `abbrev-ref'
>
> usage: git reset [--mixed | --soft | --hard | --merge | --keep] [-q] []
>
> or: git reset [-q]  [--] ...    or: git reset --patch
>   [] [--] [...]

Why is it so ? What is the difference with aliases and CLI commands ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got a full pipeline there, not just an arglist rewrite.  Put `!git` in front of it to have git run the whole thing through the shell again with the first command as `git reset`.

Comment: That seems to work for the first part, however it fails with "error: switch `m' requires a value"

Comment: Put backslashes in front of the doublequotes.