# github - commits not found

Tags: git, github, git-commit

When using github, this is what I usually do:

- `git pull` to make sure if everything is up-to-date
- `git add .` to add all my changes
- `git commit -m "some message"` to commit my changes
- `git push` to push my changes

After every change on my local files, I do the same above operations and go check on the website. The changes are there and everyone can see them. They exist on both local and remote repos. But once in a while, all my commits disappear and they're somehow discarded. I noticed that this happen whenever a colleague working on the same repo makes a change.

If this helps:

- `git log` shows that my commits are logged
- `git checkout master` says that I am already on master.
- My Github profile says that I committed X number of commits to the repository, but when I click on them, it says "commits not found".

When on the master branch, are `git push` and `git push origin master` different?

I would like to know If I am doing something wrong here, so I can avoid doing it in future commits.

Comment: When you check with `git log`, do they appear?

Comment: @Syden yes they appear

Comment: You push to your own branch or to `master`? (or you haven't pushed yet) More info would help.

Comment: So the commits are indeed logged, what you don't see are the changes you've done in the remote repo files?

Comment: So after making a change to my files in the local repo, I use `git pull` to make sure everything is up-to-date, `git add .`, `git commit` and then `git push`. And when I check on Github (website), the changes are all there. But later on, after my colleague makes a change, they disappear, like they were discarded or something. If it helps, `git checkout master` says I am already on master.

Comment: Just to clarify, you make the `pull` after making changes in your local repo? Ideally you would `pull` before starting to work on changes, `pull` basically does a `fetch` & `merge`, so that is what could be overriding your changes. On a side note if that's not the case maybe your other contributor is not following the same procedure?

Comment: Basically, we are working on different files. And most of the times my files are new. So, I assume when I do a pull after making the changes. It does not affect much. And I can see the changes on the remote repository (website, master branch). The problem is when he makes a commit, all my changes are gone. They're not even in the history. It's like he is creating a whole new repository every time he makes a change.

Comment: Maybe he's not pulling to update therefore just pushing his changes?

Comment: @Syden Thank you so much for your time. So, I understand that, aside from pulling after the changes, my procedure is correct. I will check with my colleague.

Comment: You are welcome, so far with it seems correct on your end, but if you gather new data feel free to share it and maybe we can isolate what's wrong ;)

Comment: Yes sure. I will keep this thread updated.

Comment: sure that git reports no error during operations ?

Comment: Sounds like your colleague is occasionally accidently force pushing (or resetting) the work you pushed to that branch. Shared write permissions does give opportunities for such misunderstandings.

Comment: I wonder if your colleague is doing a `rebase` of some of the public commits?

Comment: @Syden mystery solved: my colleague was using `git push --force` as @VonC suspected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The problem is when he makes a commit, all my changes are gone. They're not even in the history. It's like he is creating a whole new repository every time he makes a change.

That would only happen if he forced a push

```
git push --force
```

On GitHub, you could at least [protect your `master` branch](https://github.com/blog/2051-protected-branches-and-required-status-checks).

> When on the `master` branch, are `git push` and `git push origin master` different?

You can check the [output of `git branch -avv`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12538667/6309): it should show that master has an upstream (remote tracking) branch `origin/master`. In that case, `git push` is enough.
See "[Why do I need to explicitly push a new branch?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17096880/6309)"

Comment: thank you, and thank you all for your input. This thread was really helpful and full of information. Indeed, I just asked my colleague and he admitted using `git push --force`. Apparently he had some issues himself and he used `git push --force` without thinking about the consequences :(
So, at the end what I was doing was correct, since I was using `git pull` and `git push` on my local HEAD branch which is tracking `origin/master`. Thanks!

Comment: great catch VonC!