# git diff between local branch and remote tracking branch

Tags: git, git-diff

I simply want to get a non-zero exit code if there is a diff between a local branch and the remote tracking branch.

For example, say the local branch is foo, and I have it checked out, so the diff command would be:

```
git fetch origin
git diff --exit-code remotes/origin/foo
```

However, my question is - is there a generic/programmatic way to run this kind of diff command for any local branch? I want to diff a local branch with the remote tracking branch, generically.

Comment: Yes, you could write a script which uses the local branch name (e.g. `foo`) as a parameter, and uses the rest of what you wrote above as a template.

Comment: That assumes the remote tracking branch has the name foo it in, etc. Is there some way to programmatically get the name of the remote tracking branch?

Comment: Got it...I was half expecting you to ask that.  [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/171550/find-out-which-remote-branch-a-local-branch-is-tracking).

Comment: Still not seeing a good generic/programmatic way to do this.

Comment: You seem to asking a few question lately about automating things in Git which I would just type out by hand.  May I ask if you are doing some devops infrastructure work?

Comment: writing developer tools for myself and others yes

Comment: `<branch>@{upstream}`

Comment: ah yes torek to the rescue, I think I knew that, can you pls add an answer? thanks

Answer (score 0):

To reliably programmatically get the upstream for your current branch, you can use:

```
HEAD@{upstream}
```

so in this context, it would be:

```
git diff HEAD HEAD@{upstream}
```

and for all I know, that might be the default, when you run:

```
git diff
```

without anymore arguments; I prefer to be explicit though.