# Git Diff Stopped Working on Master Branch

Tags: git, visual-studio-code

On Windows 10, using Visual Studio Code and GitLens, my ability to diff between remotes and local branches works fine...except for on the master branch.  On the master branch I'm choosing to compare `origin/Master to master`.  I'm correctly told that there are dozens of changed files.

[image]

When I click on any of the changed files, I'm consistently given the same result:

[image]

No matter what kind of file change I select on the left (add, delete, modify), the comparison shows one changed blank line.

The weirdness does not end there.  If I type `git status` I'm given this response:

```
On branch master
Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git restore <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
    modified:   .gitignore

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

In this example, there is indication of neither how many commits "behind" I am, nor that I am "up to date."  If I switch to any other branch and issue `git status`, I am given a "normal" message about being "up to date" or how "behind" or "ahead" I am.  Likewise, GitLens correctly shows diffs of the files on those branches.

In short, something is screwed up with the master branch.  Any ideas?

I've consulted [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1580596/how-do-i-make-git-ignore-file-mode-chmod-changes) about chmod changes or cr/lf changes.  I don't think any of that applies.

For what it is worth, when I attempt `git diff` I'm shown this:

```
diff --git a/.gitignore b/.gitignore
index 17e65aa..8dfbc42 100644
--- a/.gitignore
+++ b/.gitignore
@@ -27,3 +27,6 @@ override.tf.json

 # Do not commit bin files that have been compiled
 vpc_transit/bin/*
+
+# Python
+__pycache__
\ No newline at end of file
```

### Update

[Github ticket with Gitlens](https://github.com/eamodio/vscode-gitlens/issues/941).

Comment: *Probably* not relevant, but why is `origin/Master` capitalized when `master` is all lowercase? Given Windows' case-folding tricks, if the actual name is `origin/master`, this sort of thing sometimes works and sometimes fails, in ways that appear very mysterious. (They're actually well-defined but depend on a lot of internal state, including file-system files that may not be used for anything except making things mysterious, and may be cleaned up by Git before a future command, making things even more mysterious.)

Comment: @torek I think you are on to something.  Just now, based on [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/171550/find-out-which-remote-branch-a-local-branch-is-tracking), I ran `git branch -vv`.  Looks like master has no remote tracking branch. :(

Comment: I don't use these Visual Studio thingies, but from the command line, you can `git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/master master` to set the upstream of `master` to `origin/master`. See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37770467/why-do-i-have-to-git-push-set-upstream-origin-branch/37770744#37770744

Comment: Whoa!  That helped, `git status` now works correctly, but the diffing problem remains the same.  Still investigating.