# How to checkout a file from the current tracking branch?

Tags: git, git-checkout

We would like to checkout the current file from a the currently tracked remote branch. Currently we have:

```
git fetch && git checkout origin/main RoboFile.php
```

But we need to change this code for each branch. If we are currently on develop, we would need to call

```
git fetch && git checkout origin/develop RoboFile.php
```

instead.

Is there a straight forward way to unify this command?

Comment: See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9753364/8564999. (In essence, call this command to get the corresponding remote branch name `git rev-parse --abbrev-ref --symbolic-full-name @{u}`)

Comment: We don't need to `rev-parse` it, do we? `git checkout @{u}` works fine. Try `git fetch && git checkout @{u} RoboFile.php`

Comment: Great, `@{u}` seems to work. Please post as an answer :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The branch-agnostic way to refer to some local branch's remote counterpart is [the `[<branchName>]@{upstream}` construct](https://git-scm.com/docs/revisions#Documentation/revisions.txt-emltbranchnamegtupstreamemegemmasterupstreamememuem) (`@{u}` in short form).

Just do

```
git fetch && git checkout @{u} -- RoboFile.php
```

Note : `--` is not strictly necessary here, but it's a good practice to explicitly separate options and paths. ([doc](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout#Documentation/git-checkout.txt---))

---

*(**Note in answer to above comments:** `git rev-parse` is superfluous here, since `@{u}` already will be substituted with the ref it describes, namely the remote-tracking branch associated (for pull) with the (currently checked out if you omitted `<branchName>` since `HEAD@{u}` is then implied) local one.)*